# Who was using a spid 2 hours earlier in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019, dmv

I have a specific spid from 2 hours ago, and would like to know who was using it.
Is this possible? Is this stored in the cache, some DMV, Ringbuffer? SQL Server 2019.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that is logged or kept by default, you'd need to setup a trace/audit/etc. to get the information you desire.